# Sorting a table using macro

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, macros

hoping this newbie here could get some assistance with sorting using macro please.

I have a table ranging D:R to be sorted.

Firstly, the whole table needs to be sorted in ascending order according to column Q.

Then the same table get sorted in ascending order according to column P.

Lastly the whole table needs to bring yellow highlighted rows per column D to the top.

My current formula is recorded using the in-built recorder and it doesn't work.

Would anyone provide any suggestions? Many thanks in advance!

```
'Sorting for easier read
    'Check for filter, turn on if none exists
    If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("D1:R1").AutoFilter
    End If
    'Sort in order of column Q
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "Q1:Q10000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    End With
    'Sort in order of column P
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "P1:P10000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    End With
    'Bring highlighted row to the top
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("D:D" _
        ), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255 _
        , 255, 0)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that I did to sort column 52 on color `yellow`:

```
Sub SortOnDuplicates()

ws.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=52, _
    Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), _
    Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

End Sub
```

Here's one for sorting on ascending:

```
ws.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=52
With ws.ListObjects("Table1").Sort
    'Last Name
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Last Name]]"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    'First Name
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[First Name]]"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer! My table can actually vary from 2 rows to 2000 rows so with the Field:=52 indicator, does that just get changed to 2000? Also with the "Table1" is that a generic one that will just automatically pick up the applicable data? Lastly, my sort data is looking at numbers in general, how would I be looking to replace the first and last name section? Sorry to be such a noob.

Comment: Field 52 is column 52. If all your values are in a true table, 2000 rows is nothing for excel.